# How to enable setTouchAFPosition Sony Remote Camera Api

Tags: android, sony, sony-camera-api

I am working with Sony Camera Qx30. Currently, I am working on focus. I am using setTouchAFPosition to set a focus on specific coordinates and its working perfectly when I enable LOCK-AF from Sony's Playmemories application, and when to turn it off the function setTouchAFPosition returns "Not Available" Error.

Can some one please tell me which function I use to enable or disable LOCK-AF mode??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I achieve this with setTrackingFocus method.